# Enter data after three clicks in C

Tags: c, count, click, show

I have '.,/' on a button and I need to print:

'.' if clicked once
 ',' if clicked twice
 '/' if clicked thrice

how to manage this in **C**?

Comment: Can you put here the code that runs the button?

Comment: i was just trying to play with tick counts in while loop, but it doesn't worked....actually i have to do this on a touch screen LCD in C, so its a button control which calls a function on click...

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have a timer nevertheless for unbouncing your button, you could use that for detecting gaps between keypresses.

So you count the keypresses, and if the gap is too long, you reset the counter.